# how to get string array values out of strings.xml and in to an arraylist [android]

Tags: android

```
products.add(new Product(getResources().getString(R.string.ChecklistData)),
              R.drawable.ic_launcher, false));
```

My StringArray in xml call CheckListData and the Arraylist that i want to add is call products

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ChecklistData)
```

instead of

```
getResources().getString(R.string.ChecklistData)
```

if `ChecklistData` is `<string-array >` in `strings.xml`

Answer (score 0):

if ChecklistData is the string array then,use:

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ChecklistData)
```